# How to check for class inheritance in Coffeescript Mocha Test?

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js, should.js

How do I check for the class of an object in a mocha spec in Coffeescript?

I have tried the following:

```
# foo.coffee
class Foo
module.exports = new Foo()

# foo_spec.coffee
should  = require 'should'
{ Foo } = require 'foo'
foo = new Foo
foo.should.be.an.instanceOf(Foo)
```

However, I receive `ReferenceError Foo is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this to be the easiest approach:

```
# foo.coffee
class Foo
module.exports = new Foo()
module.exports.Foo = Foo # IMPORTANT, exports the actual class Foo


# foo_spec.coffee
should  = require 'should'
{ Foo } = require 'foo' # Requires said class Foo
foo = new Foo
foo.should.be.an.instanceOf(Foo)
```