# Coffeescript unit test failing with Mocha, Should, Node.js

Tags: unit-testing, coffeescript, mocha.js, should.js

I am trying to run a sample CoffeeScript unit test for a CoffeeScript sample class hierarchy, using Mocha. But I keep getting errors and it doesn't seem I can fix them without some help. This is my sample CoffeeScript file, in /src folder :

```
 #Animal.coffee
  class Animal
    constructor: (@name) ->

    move: (meters) ->
      console.log @name + " moved #{meters}m."

  class Snake extends Animal
    move: ->
      console.log "Slithering..."
      super 5

  class Horse extends Animal
    move: ->
      console.log "Galloping..."
      super 45

  #module.exports = new Snake()
  module.exports.Snake = Snake
```

And this is the CoffeeScript Unit Test in /Tests folder :

```
  #AnimalTest.coffee
  should  = require 'should'
  { Snake } = require "../src/Animal"

  describe 'sample', ->
     it 'should pass', ->
         snake = new Snake "Venomous python"
         snake.should.be.an.instanceOf(Snake)
```

I have installed all these libraries globally. So when I execute this command through command line (Windows 7) :

```
   Desktop>mocha --compilerscoffee:coffee-script/register Tests
```

It throws me this error:

```
    desktop\Tests\sampleTest.coffee:15
    snake.should.be.an.instanceOf(Snake);
    ^
    ReferenceError: snake is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\users\ap\desktop\Tests\AnimalTest.coffee:8:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\users\ap\desktop\Tests\AnimalTest.coffee:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.loadFile (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-sc
    ript\lib\coffee-script\register.js:16:19)
    at Module.load (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script
    \lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:172:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib
    \mocha.js:169:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha
    .js:356:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\
    bin\_mocha:359:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I am using CoffeeScript version 1.7.1, Mocha version 1.18.2 and Node version 0.10.26. I have tried looking everywhere and tried all combinations between the tests, but I cannot figure out for my life how to make it create the objects successfully and run the test.

For reference, I tried these, of all other combinations : 
[Requiring CoffeeScript file from within another CoffeeScript file with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939672/requiring-coffeescript-file-from-within-another-coffeescript-file-with-nodejs)

[How to check for class inheritance in Coffeescript Mocha Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335719/how-to-check-for-class-inheritance-in-coffeescript-mocha-test)

Can someone point out what could possibly be wrong?

**Update 1:** Modified everything as pointed by dule, but now I get this error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'should'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
     at require (module.js:380:17)
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ap\Desktop\Tests\AnimalTest.coffee:2:11)
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ap\Desktop\Tests\AnimalTest.coffee:2:1)
     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
     at Object.loadFile (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-sc
     ript\lib\coffee-script\register.js:16:19)
     at Module.load (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script
     \lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
     at require (module.js:380:17)
     at C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:172:27
     at Array.forEach (native)
     at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib
     \mocha.js:169:14)
     at Mocha.run (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha
     .js:356:31)
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\
     bin\_mocha:359:16)
     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
     at startup (node.js:119:16)
     at node.js:902:3
```

**Update 2:** I made the following changes to the AnimalTest script and the test passed.

```
  should  = require ("../npm/node_modules/should/should")
  { Snake } = require ("../src/Animal.coffee")

  describe 'sample', ->
     it 'should pass', ->
    console.log(new Snake "Venomous python")
```

However, for some reason, creating an object and saving it for use, still fails. And I get the same `snake not defined` error.

Comment: snake is not defined because you're not requiring the right file, `require`s are relative to the the current file, not relative to the project root (see my answer below), but that isn't your only problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is totally weird. An explanation is more than welcome! This is what I did and the test passed :

```
 should  = require ("../npm/node_modules/should/should")
 { Snake } = require ("../src/Animal.coffee")

 describe 'sample', ->
    it 'should pass', ->
      (new Snake "Venomous python").should.be.an.instanceOf(Snake)
```

Comment: This was silly, but let me explain. I am using Sublime Text 2 as my editor. For some reason, it was not being able to comprehend the indentation on the line where I use the snake object, although to me it looked properly aligned with the one where its being created. So, the next object was falling out of scope. A little erasing and rewriting did the trick. And it works now! Yucks! Indentation-based scoping!

Comment: Could it be that you had tabs instead of spaces (or vice versa)?

Comment: Could be, I am not sure. I am new to coffeescript and this whole Node environment. So, I thought the problem was something I don't know about and people assisting me kept telling there was something wrong with the require. I guess, otherwise, the question would not even have landed here, I would have figured it out eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a number of issues. Try the following:

src/animal.coffee:

```
class Animal
    constructor: (@name) ->

    move: (meters) ->
        console.log @name + " moved #{meters}m."

class Snake extends Animal
    move: ->
        console.log "Slithering..."
        super 5

module.exports.Snake = Snake
```

tests/animalTest.coffee

```
should  = require "should"
{ Snake } = require "../src/animal"

describe 'sample', ->
    it 'should pass', ->
        snake = new Snake "Venomous python"
        snake.should.be.an.instanceOf(Snake)
```

Then run (from proj root):

```
mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register tests
```

Comment: Just to enumerate some of the issues with your original: (1) you do an instanceof check on Snake but import SnakeObj, (2) you dont need to do a full relative path when importing a node module like `should`, (3) don't know why you're exporting a snake object using `new Snake()`, (4) the compiler for coffee-script should be coffee-script not coffeescript

Comment: 1) I tried importing Snake as is, it didn't work. So next I tried importing SnakeObj, as was shown in one of the linked stack overflow questions. 
2) I have tried importing the node module should as is, but it was not being able to find should. I have installed all the libraries globally so I thought that could be the reason its not being able to 
find them.
3) That's the same as mentioned in the linked question.
4) It was a copy-paste, but don't know how the hyphen got lost. I rechecked I have the hyphen on my command line.

Comment: (1) It should be fine as either, as long as you're consistent in the file, (2) should should be installed local to the project (`npm install --save should`), (3) the linked question is answered by the same person asking the question, and just looks like a line he forgot to remove in the answer

Comment: I made all the changes and got the error I updated above. Also did `npm install --save should` and then ran the command.

Answer (score -1):

I got test case broken *randomly* when using **CoffeeScript** 1.8.0, **mocha** 1.21.4.

The test case can be approved by hand, but it failed in **mocha** with strange exceptions like "undefined function...".  Too trivial to copy the long long fails, exceptions, stack traces...

To solve it:

- Enjoy the trouble
- Commented out all failed testing cases
- Try to use more *javascript directly*
- Try to use other unit test tools, such as [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit)
- It sounds stupid, but when debugging becomes terrible, **all happens**, at least to me.